# Basic covering space question

Tags: covering-spaces

Given a path connected metric space $X$ and a cover $\tilde{X}$ which is also a path connected metric space with covering map $E$, then is $E$ a local isometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true:  For example take $X= S^1$ with subspace topology of $\mathbb R^2$.

and $\tilde{X}= \mathbb R$.   Define map $p:\mathbb R\to S^1$  by $p(t)= (\cos 2\pi t, \sin2\pi t)$ . Then this is covering map but not local isometry.